# CSS Float-right *sometimes* causes elements to appear outside parent div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This may be a problem with my CSS or a bug in Chrome, I'm trying to find out.
Basically, I have a form with two buttons that is styled to float to the right of its parent div so that it appears in the bottom right corner:

```
.event-block form {
display: inline;
float: right;                      
}
```

This works as expected on wide screens like 1920x1080. But when viewing the page on mobile (Chrome/Android), the buttons appear below where they should, outside the parent div, as seen here: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARydK.png)

HOWEVER, if I then navigate to any other page, and press "Back", the layout is now correct, as seen in [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHghc.png).

What is the pattern here? What causes this type of layout error when using `float: right` and why does it correct itself when navigating back from a different page?

PHP code: (This appears just after the colored heading to the left of the form)

```
<form action="/script/event_rsvp.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="event-id" value=<?php echo "'".$e['event_id']."'"; ?> />
            <?php if($_SESSION['type']==0) : ?>
                <input type="submit" class="sc-button" name="guest-rsvp" value="&#10004; Sign Up" />
            <?php elseif(in_array($e['event_id'], $signedUpIds)) : ?>
                You are signed up for this event!
                <input type="submit" class="sc-button" name="cancel" style="background-color: firebrick" value="&#128473; Cancel" />
            <?php else : ?>
                <input type="submit" class="sc-button" name="member-rsvp" style="background-color: limegreen" value="&#10004; Sign Up" />
            <?php endif; ?>

            <input type="button" class="sc-button" value="&#9993; Contact Host" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Attached screen have a different width. So eighter screen width or used font is caused to your issue because text (Sample free play event description) and Second box title (Sample Tournament) is dropping to next line.

**Solution:**

1. You can reduce font-size of dropped paragraph and title by `1px` or `2px`.
2. For mobile view take your button in a new line, but the first option is better because that will resolve your dropping issues too.

Comment: Why would the layout correct itself when navigating back to this page from somewhere else, though?

Comment: For exact solution can share any fiddle?

Comment: No idea what you're saying.

Comment: I mean, can you share your issue with complete code anywhere like [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)